# match regex - How to get the difference between the two strings when matched

Tags: javascript

I perform a test if a string contains a substring, if yes, I would like to have the substring that not matched

```
var string = "Hello world";
var toMatch = new RegExp('world', 'i');

if (string.match(toMatch)){
  // should return "Hello "
}
```

Comment: If you are matching words and not text within text, I'd suggest you split, and filter.

Comment: Are you trying to do anything that `.replace(regex,"")` does not accomplish?

Comment: why not just do a replace all instead of regex

Comment: And what if there is not a match?

Comment: @Andrew, just need to have the substring when there is a match, if there is no match then nothing.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Do you mean nothing or an empty string? And what if there is more than one match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `replace()`:

```
var string = "Hello world";
var toMatch = new RegExp('world', 'i');

var newString=string.replace(string.match(toMatch),"");
```

If you want to return, use

```
return string.replace(string.match(toMatch),"");
```

It will give you a string without "world" if it contained "world" and unmodified string if there was no "world"